# ¿Como solucionar el error "error HRESULT E_FAIL de una llamada a un componente COM,"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net, framework

Tengo ese problema en mi visual studio 2022 al crear un proyecto ASP.NET Framework Ya intente varios metodos y no me funciona no se si alguien puede ayudarme[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]